# NameError: name 'tree' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, spyder

Hey I'm new to Python and I am trying to follow along with a tutorial but I get this error:

> NameError: name 'tree' is not defined.

The objective is obviously for the program to determine whether the fruit is an apple or orange based on the input of features. I'm using Python 3.6 with the spyder editor on Win 10. I'm sure it's something simple, thanks for any help!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

# features = [[140, "smooth"], [130, "smooth"], [150, "bumpy"], [170, "bumpy"]]
# labels = ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange"]
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]
# We build a "Decision Tree" yes/no -> yes/no
# clf means classifier
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
# Think of "fit" as "find patters in data"
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print (clf.predict([[160, 0]]))
```

Comment: You have to import some module. It is probably written in the tutorial which.

Answer (score 20):

Add this to the top of your code:

```
from sklearn import tree
```

This is assuming that you are studying machine learning.

Comment: I downloaded anaconda which must include sklearn because it worked after I did the import. Thanks a lot @BoobyTrap, cant believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this `from sklearn import tree` it does not work on my system.

Then I tried this `from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier` and worked.

This is after installing `sklearn` of course.

Comment: Why this answer was voted down!, would you give a good reason?

Answer (score 0):

One needs to import lib before using.
So, to use `DecisionTreeClassifier`, either use below code to import & run.

```
from sklearn import tree.
...
dtree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

Another way is to import the class itself & use it directly. E.g.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
...
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down but resolved my issue. Import statement is correct & worked for. Probably an explanation could have worked.

Answer (score 0):

from sklearn.tree import _tree

...this is the one you need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
except:
    pass
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

- Python 3.9.10
- Mac OS M1
- also for a side note tested in py3.7 it imports without any problems